# Differential equation $y''+\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right) y' -2y=0$ method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

What method is the best for solving differential equation:

$$y''+\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right) y' -2y=0$$

with conditions: $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Defining a solution near zero seems iffy to me.

Comment: I tried solving it by finding roots of polynomial and I was wondering if series method works.

Comment: You should include that attempt in the post. Please edit it to include the try.

Comment: Once that solution is found, the second (ignoring BCs) can be found via the reduction of order https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/ReductionofOrder.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y''+\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right) y' -2y=0$$
By inspection one see that changing $x$ into $-x$ doesn't change the ODE. Thus the solution functions are even. This draw to the change of variable :
$$X=x^2\quad\implies\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=2x\frac{dy}{dX}\quad\implies\quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=4X\frac{d^2y}{dX^2}+2\frac{dy}{dX}$$
$$4X\frac{d^2y}{dX^2}+2\frac{dy}{dX}+\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right) 2x\frac{dy}{dX} -2y=0$$

$$4X\frac{d^2y}{dX^2}+2\left( X + 2\right)\frac{dy}{dX} -2y=0$$
An obvious particular solution is $y=c(X+2)=c(x^2+2)$.

With $c=\frac12$ this solution satisfies both the ODE and the conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$ :
$$\boxed{y(x)=x^2+\frac12}$$

Just for the fun one can continue to solve the ODE.

Reduction of order :

$$y(X)=(X+2)u(X)\quad\implies\quad \frac{dy}{dX}=(X+2)\frac{du}{dX}+u \quad\implies\quad \frac{d^2y}{dX^2}=(X+2)\frac{d^2u}{dX^2}+2\frac{du}{dX}$$
$$2X(X+2)\frac{d^2u}{dX^2} +(X^2+8X+4)\frac{du}{dX} =0$$
Change of function : $v(X)=\frac{du}{dX}$
$$2X(X+2)\frac{dv}{dX} +(X^2+8X+4)v =0$$
$\frac{dv}{v}=-\frac{X^2+8X+4}{2X(X+2)}dX$
$$\ln|v|=-\int \frac{X^2+8X+4}{2X(X+2)}dX = -X-2\ln|X|-4\ln|X+2|+constant$$
This leads successively to $v(X)$ , $u(X)$ , y(X) , y(x).
$$y(x)=c_1(x^2+2)+c_2\left(2e^{-x^2/2}+(x^2+2)\text{Ei}(-x^2/2) \right)$$
Ei is the special function "exponential integral" : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html

The condition $y(0)=1$ implies $c_2=0$ because Ei$(0)$ isn't finite.

And $2c_1=1 \quad c_1=\frac12$. The particular solution satisfying both the ODE and the conditions is :
$$y(x)=x^2+\frac12$$